# A technical detail in Fary Milnor Theorem

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm learning the Fary-Milnor theorem. At the end of the proof, I have a technical problem which is :
 that a closed curve $l$ in $R^{3}$ whose z-coordinate has absolute maximum $M$ and absolute minimum $m$ and the cross section of $(x,y,z_{0})\cap l$ ,$z_{0}\in (m,M)$ contains exactly two points, prove that this curve $l$ is unknotted.
[image]

We have to construct a homotopy between this curve and a circle and at every moment of homotopy the corresponding curve is also homotopic with a circle. I want to find a neat way.

Comment: The usual definition of unknotted is that you can fill in a (topological) disk. That's what your picture shows (although you still have to prove it). Once you have a disk filled in, you can easily isotope your curve to a small circle in the disk.

Comment: @TedShifrin  Can you provide some details? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Details for *what*? Do you see how to prove that you get just two points on the curve for $z$ values between $m$ and $M$? Do you see why you fill in something homeomorphic to a disk if so? And can you draw a tiny circle in that disk?

Answer (score 2):

As it was explained by Ted Shifrin, the knot is trivial since one can fill in a disk; this disc wept by horizontal chords.

If you want a more formal proof, then you need to choose a definition of knot and trival knot.
One possibility is to define it as a 3D-polygon.
With this definition, a formal proof is given [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2203.15137); see Proposition 1.1.